# C# MVC Solution?

Tags: c#, janus, telerik-open-access

I have recently been tasked with updating a system done in C#. I am coming from a Kohana MVC web based development but have experience in C#.

Problem is: My solution is in some 'weird' namind convention. I would like to know what it could be and how to load the solution in VS 2010 Ultimate.

```
MySolution.BusinessLogic
MySolution.Common
MySolution.Contracts
MySolution.DataAccess
MySolution.DatabaseInstaller
MySolution.Entities
MySolution.Reporting
MySolution.UI
MySolution.UIControls
```

How does this work? Do I need to edit each folder separately or there is a way to load the whole solution in my developer IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a `.sln` solution file, probably in the project root folder. That is typically what you would open in Visual Studio. You can open individual project files (`.csproj`), but its much easier/better to work with a solution that contains all required projects.

Comment: Thing is... all the files are in the folders shown. And each folder has a .sln solution file. So I don't know if each folder is a separate program or they all work as one.

Comment: Each project will create its own executable. It seems strange to have a solution for each project. But a solution is simply a container for projects, so you could create a new solution and add all of the projects to it.

Comment: When I try to compile I get errors like "Error 8 The type or namespace name 'Entities' does not exist in the namespace 'mbi.MySolution' (are you missing an assembly reference?) \MySolution.UI\MySolution.UI\Controller\ApplicationController.cs"
"

Comment: You are probably missing a reference. Check your references for an assembly named similar to `mbi.MySolution`. The properties tab will tell your where VS is looking for the dll - it may not be where it should be.

Comment: I will create a new solution and add all these projects under it and see how that works together. Thanks for your time.